# python subclass can't import superclass from superclass

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

First of all is very possible I can making a terrible mistake. But let's go!

My superclass (project/src/mlbase.py)

```
from preprocessing import PreProcessing

class MLBase:
  preProcessing = None

  def __init__(self,preprocessingOptions):
    self.preProcessing = PreProcessing(preProcessingOptions)
    # and more stuff here...
```

My Subclass(project/src/preprocessing.py)

```
from mlbase import MLBase
class PreProcessing(MLBase):
  def __init__(self,options):
     #processing options here... 
     pass
```

My script that is instantiating everything(project/main.py)

```
from src.mlbase import MLBase

mlb = MLBase(preProcessingOptions = {})
```

Dirs

```
  """

  project
  |
  + src
    |
    + mlbase.py
    |
    + preprocessing.py 
  |
  + main.py

  """
```

As you can see. The objective is instanciate subclasses from superclass. But I receive the following error when `src/preprocessing.py` module tries to import `MLBase` class from `src.mlbase.py`:

> ImportError: cannot import name MLBase

Why this is happening?

Comment: Should `class MBase` be `class MLBase`?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a little typo. You declared `class MBase` but tried to import `MLBase`. All you have to do is change the superclass file to this:

```
from preprocessing import PreProcessing

class MLBase: #Note that it's "MLBase", not "MBase"
  preProcessing = None

  def __init__(self,preprocessingOptions):
    self.preProcessing = PreProcessing(preProcessingOptions)
    # and more stuff here...
```

Comment: My bad! Sorry! Typing error! It's MLBase and the error persists! Can you help?

Comment: It's seems I don't need to import "preprocessing" module from "mlbase" module. This is weird! Maybe because both modules are in the same directory ?!?! I'm trying to find some reference in documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was import PreProcessing class using `from preprocessing import PreProcessing` inside the constructor method! I don't know why! I really would like to understand that!

In mlbase module:

```
class MLBase:
    def __init__(self,preProcessingOptions):
        from preprocessing import Preprocessing
        # more stuff
```

In preprocessing module

```
from mlbase import MLBase

class PreProcessing(MLBase):
    def __init__(self,preProcessingOptions):
        # more stuff
```

Too weird for me!